# Mean value of the rotation angle is 126.5°

Tags: random-variables, rotations, average, quaternions

In the paper 
"*Applications of Quaternions to Computation with Rotations*"
by Eugene Salamin, 1979 ([click here](http://www.theworld.com/~sweetser/quaternions/ps/stanfordaiwp79-salamin.pdf)),
they get 126.5 degrees as the mean value of the rotation angle of a random rotation (by integrating quaternions over the 3-sphere).

> [image]

How can I make sense of this result?
If rotation angle around a given axis can be 0..360°, should not the mean be 180? or 0 if it can be −180..180°? or 90° if you take absolute values?

Comment: I think the angles they're talking about must be in the range from $0^\circ$ to $180^\circ$.  If you rotate a circle $181^\circ$ clockwise, that's the same as $179^\circ$ counterclockwise, and I think the latter is the angle they're talking about.  But the rotations above are rotations in $3$-dimensional Euclidean space, so just plus or minus signs do not suffice to express the direction in which the sphere was rotated.

Comment: The key phrase is "Random rotations are to be chosen uniformly distributed over the 3-sphere"

Answer (score 0):

First, SO(3) of course has [its unique invariant probabilistic measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure). Hence, “random rotation” is a well-defined SO(3)-valued random variable. Each rotation (an element of SO(3)) has an uniquely defined rotation angle *θ*, from 0 to 180° (π) because of axis–angle representation. (Note that *axis* is undefined for *θ* = 0 and has two possible values for *θ* = 180°, but *θ* itself has no ambiguity.) Hence, “angle of a random rotation” is a well-defined random angle.

Why is its average closer to one end (180°) than to another (0)? In short, because there are **many 180° rotations,** whereas rotation by zero angle is unique (identity map).

Note that I ignore Spin(3) → SO(3) covering that is important in quaternionic discourse, but it won’t change the result: Haar measure on Spin(3) projected onto SO(3) gives the same Haar measure on SO(3), hence there is no difference whether do we make computations on S<sup>3</sup> of unit quaternions (the same as Spin(3)) or directly on SO(3).